# remove event listener without knowing what the call back function is

Tags: javascript, event-listener, removeeventlistener

Lets say we add a even listener to a button like this

```js
function handler(){
 alert(0)
}
btn.addEventListener("click", handler)
```

now if we want to remove event listener we can simply do:
`btn.removeEventListener("click", handler)`

but what if we don't have access to the handler function. for example, some third-party library is attaching an event listener to an element and I want to remove it.
how can we do so?

Comment: You cannot remove it without the handler/original function reference.

Comment: Only way to remove event listeners is to recreate the element

Comment: Probably you should look into `third-party library` documentation and see if there is any remove event.

Comment: `btn.replaceWith(btn.cloneNode(true));` sure there are duplicates with that answer

Comment: @epascarello just answered with a possible alternative that will not remove the event listeners, but should prevent third-party listeners from firing.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano Your solution would be the "perfect storm" where things have to line up just right.

Comment: @epascarello I know that it is not ideal, but as I wrote, the situation is not ideal from the beginning. Will add an additional note to emphasize that.

Answer (score 5):

As written in comments, you can't remove an event listener without having the callback reference unless you re-create/clone that element, which can be problematic sometimes and also does not seem to be good practice or particularly performant (***Spoiler Alert*** - None of the possible solutions can be completely considered good practice because your situation isn't ideal from the beginning).

As an alternative, you can try something like this:

```js
element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Odds are that your third-party library will be listening to the event on the `bubbling` phase. If so, doing this on the `capture` phase (see `addEventListener` third argument) will prevent your third-party listeners from firing.

Please note that this will break event propagation at the `capture` phase. This means that any listener set on the `bubbling` phase for that event, triggered on that element or any of its children will not fire. Also the remaining listeners on the `capture` phase will not fire either.

**Leveraging Event's Nature**

If you add the above event listener before your third-party library adds its own event listeners, you can be "more sure" that yours will be fired first.

Please consider that `capture` phase listeners will ALWAYS be fired before `bubbling` phase listeners and that element's DOM order will ALWAYS be respected.

What is a bit unpredictable is the execution order for multiple listeners for the same event on the same phase and on the same target element. See [Event Order](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

With that being said, if you add the above listener to the PARENT of your interested element, you can be 99% sure that your third-party library listener will not be executed and this comes with almost zero performance impact. (The remaining 1% is for the case in which the library somehow adds an event listener on the `capture` phase and on a previous ancestor than yours, that could also be the `window` object).

If you want to still fire listeners for the parent element you can filter out cases using `event.target` property.

Something like:

```js
parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (element.contains(e.target)) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);
```

**Final Note**

I took the time to write all this more as a didactic example about DOM events than as an actual working solution. This is because any possible solution that I can think about right now will have some kind of drawback, issue or limitation (performance, debugging, unpredictability, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried(It didnt work tho)

```js
function removeEListener(element, event){
    let listeners = getEventListeners(element)[event]
    try{
        listeners.forEach(listener => {
            listener.remove()
            element.removeEventListener(event, listener.listener, listener.useCapture)
        })
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}
removeEListener(document.querySelector(".btn"), 'click')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to clone node and its child elements to remove all the listeners.

```js
function recreateNode(el, withChildren) {
  if (withChildren) {
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(el.cloneNode(true), el);
  }
  else {
    var newEl = el.cloneNode(false);
    while (el.hasChildNodes()) newEl.appendChild(el.firstChild);
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
  }
}
```

Here `withChildren: true` will replace all nested elements as well.
With your question, You don't need to find out the reference function.